# What are common reasons for a company to want to reschedule an interview earlier?

Tags: interviewing

I have a 2.5 hour scheduled for next week, but the recruiting coordinator reached out asking if we could reschedule the interview for earlier. What are some common reasons this would happen, and does it look bad if I decline the reschedule? They said it would “definitely be fine to keep it to same day.

Comment: It sounds like they like you as a candidate and are keen to get you started sooner rather than later.

Comment: You're overthinking this. There could be a thousand and one reasons. Obviously, don't reschedule it earlier if it would be inconvenient for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Boss wanted to schedule a meeting
- They want to get you earlier
- The prior day seemed a bit tight on time
- They want to see their kid in a school play

Things get rescheduled all the time. It happens.